# how can i dynamically update my nested object within another object, within an array?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an array and inside each array is a json object with each day of the week, so my array would look something like this:

```
var array = [
    {
        "wednesday":{
            "notes":"some notes for Wednesday"
        },
    },
    {
        "thursday":{
            "notes":"some notes for Thursday"
        }
    }
];
```

i can get away with updating my object directly by calling the following:

```
array[0].wednesday.notes = "updating Wednesday notes";
```

However, I need to update it dynamically....

I have a function that looks something like this, I need to dynamically call the day of the week on my json object and not be locked into just wednesday, i need to be able to call wednesday, thursday, friday etc on my object, how can i do this?

```
function updateObject(index, empNum) {
    console.log(index+", "+empNum)
    array[index].employee = $("#employee_" + empNum).val();
    array[index].wednesday.notes = $("#employee_" + empNum + "_wed_notes").val();
    array[index].wednesday.start = $("#employee_" + empNum + "_wed_shift_start").val();
    array[index].wednesday.lunch = $("#employee_" + empNum + "_wed_lunch").val();
    array[index].wednesday.end = $("#employee_" + empNum + "_wed_shift_end").val();
    array[index].wednesday.short_day = $("#employee_" + empNum + "_wed_short_day").is(':checked');
    array[index].wednesday.lack_of_work = $("#employee_" + empNum + "_wed_lack_of_work").is(':checked');
    array[index].wednesday.full_day = $("#employee_" + empNum + "_wed_full_day").is(':checked');

    var row_count = $("input[id*='employee_" + empNum + "_wed_job_']").length;
    for (var i = 0; i < row_count; i++) {
      var data = {};
      data.job = $("input[id*='employee_" + empNum + "_wed_job_']").eq(i).val();
      data.hrs = $("input[id*='employee_" + empNum + "_wed_hrs_']").eq(i).val();
      data.cost_code = $("input[id*='employee_" + empNum + "_wed_cost_code_']").eq(i).val();
      data.st = $("input[id*='employee_" + empNum + "_wed_st_']").eq(i).is(':checked');
      data.ot = $("input[id*='employee_" + empNum + "_wed_ot_']").eq(i).is(':checked');
      data.dt = $("input[id*='employee_" + empNum + "_wed_dt_']").eq(i).is(':checked');
      array[index].wednesday.data[i] = data;
    }
  }
```

i tried something like doing 
    array[index].[thursday].notes = "x";

but unfortunately that doesnt work, i need to be able to call the day of the week i need when i call the function

so i need it to be something like `updateObject(2,1,"thursday");`

Comment: You seem to already know how to use bracket notation, and adding another argument to the function should be trivial ?

Comment: unfortunately i dont know how to use bracket notation, or at least im not clear on what that is =/

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/vjon7k13/

Comment: i'm a bit confused, does each object in your array contain only one day? if so why not use an object instead of an array?

Comment: @Punit no it doesnt just contain one day, it contains a full week, that was my error on how i typed up my question

Comment: So... Does it have to be an array?  Why is it an array?  It seems simpler to have something like: var days = {"wed": {}};

Comment: @AndrewIce i assume each element in the array is supposed to represent a week. so you'd be able to access a specific day by first specifying the week number, then by the day.

Comment: True, wasn't thinking of it from a Calendar POV.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to use the [bracket notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_accessors#Bracket_notation) to access the correct element in your array/objects.

This function would let you enter the week number (array index) as well as the day you want to update.

```js
var array = [
    {
        "wednesday":{
            "notes":"some notes for Wednesday"
        },
    },
    {
        "thursday":{
            "notes":"some notes for Thursday"
        }
    }
];

function updateArray(index, day, newNotes) {
  array[index][day].notes = newNotes;
}

console.log('before', array);

updateArray(1, 'thursday', 'updated notes');

console.log('after', array);
```

Comment: No need to pass both index and day, passing one will allow you to infer the other.

Comment: @StephanBijzitter that's not true. have another look at the array structure. each element in the array is an object that could have multiple days.

Comment: You can use ES6 Filters to do it for you as well!

Comment: @AndrewIce OP specified in this comment http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41068528/how-can-i-dynamically-update-my-nested-object-within-another-object-within-an-a/41068651?noredirect=1#comment69344475_41068528, that each object contains a full week, therefore multiple days.

Comment: Comments can be deleted.

Answer (score 0):

You can access all your data as so:

```
const updateObject = (index, empNum) => {
  const i = array[index], k = Object.keys(i)[0]
  if (!k) {return console.error("Invalid Data at index",index)}
  i[k].notes = `Whatever you want with ${empNum}`
}
```

The function isolates the key given at a certain location and accesses it.

Example: `updateObject(0, "15 employees")`

If you would rather have ^^ do it by day then your function would look like:

```
const updateObject = (day, empNum) => {
  const i = array.map(r => {
    const k = Object.keys(r)[0];if (!k) {return false}
    return r[k]
  }).filter(r => r)[0]
  if (!i) {return console.error("Invalid Day [%s] provided",day)}
  i.notes = `Whatever you want with ${empNum}`
}
```

Not you can use it like: `updateObject('tuesday', "15 employees")`

Comment: I doubt the asker would know how to transpile this code, given this question. Good solution, though. The arrow function however is simply clutter.